# Как сделать так, чтобы по клику на любую ячейку таблицы в красный фон красились все ячейки этой колонки?

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица:
Дана следующая HTML таблица:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы по клику на любую ячейку таблицы в красный фон красились все ячейки этой колонки?
у меня не получается сделать, чтобы все ячейки колонки окрашивались одновременно по нажатию на одну ячейку.

```
let tds = document.querySelectorAll('#table td');

tds.forEach(function(td){
        td.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(td.dataset.col==this.dataset.col){           
            td.style.backgroundColor="red";
        }   
        
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('#table td')

tds.forEach(td => {
  td.addEventListener('click', e => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`#table [data-col="${e.target.dataset.col}"]`).forEach(e =>
      e.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    )
  })
})
```

```css
#table td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!! Два часа мучилась...

Comment: Не за что, насчёт того как вы пытались сделать это, постарайтесь выбирать элементы как только можно конкретней (как например я сделал в этом примере), а не проверять все, т.к. к примеру если будет 1000+ или того больше элементов, то тогда будет проверка всех этих элементов и на мало мощных устройствах это может вызвать проблемы с производительностью, хоть и временные.

Comment: @Виктория Ой да, забыл сказать, если вы посчитали мой ответ полезным можете нажать на стрелку вверх (слева сверху от моего ответа), а если мой ответ является решением для вашей проблемы, то нажмите на галочку (Также слева сверху от моего ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Вы были очень близки. Просто вам нужен либо второй цикл for, либо через селекторы получить все те элементы которые хотите закрасить (к примеру [data-col='3']).

Мой алгоритм через цикл for:

```js
let tds = document.querySelectorAll('#table td');

tds.forEach(function(td){
        td.addEventListener('click',function(){
        let col =this.dataset.col
        tds.forEach(el=>{
          if(el.dataset.col==col){           
            el.style.backgroundColor="red";
          }
        })
         
        
    })
})
```

```css
table{
width:100%;
 height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-col="1"></td>
        <td data-col="2"></td>
        <td data-col="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```